# NSDictionary: is order of iteration preserved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

Say I want to access all objects in some NSDictionary object.
I want to iterate like this:

```
for (key in dict){}
```

Is it guaranteed that for each run the objects in the dictionary will be accessed in the same order?

PS. Let me explain my question more thoroughly: if I iterate dictionary once and access keys in some concrete order - will I have the **same** order on **second** iteration attempt?

Comment: My question was different: if I iterate dictionary once and access keys in some concrete order - will I have the same order on second iteration attempt?

Comment: what are the stored values datatype, mixed id<NSObject> or custom made class objects?

Answer (score 2):

Sorting of keys is **not guaranteed** because of the nature a key is placed inside the `NSDictionary`. But that is only the half answer. read on...

If we iterate thru the dict with a **for** (**NSString* key in dict**) loop or
 even more unspecific with **for** (**id<NSCopying> key in dict**) loop then we use actually `NSEnumeration`. Those kind of iterations are unpredictable to you. `NSEnumeration` and `NSFastEnumeration` do not iterate the dict with indexes. They go thru by addresses or hashes of keys, so to speak. Thats also a blurry answer that is not complete.

Keys inside a dict are unique compared to other keys in the same dict.
Which is the great thing and why you would use a `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` instead of indexed `NSArray` or `NSPointerArray` or unspecific `NSSet`, and specially offered datatypes as `NSOrderedSet`, `NSOrderedCollection`. `NSMapTable` and `NSHashTable` tend to behave like NSDictionaries but they have a completely different way how they store the keys and how they iterate.

So what happens when you rewrite a keyed value in NSDictionary?

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"A" : @(1234),
    @"B" : @(4321)
}
NSMutableDictionary *mutabledict = [dict mutablecopy];
mutabledict[@"A"] = @(5678); //beware this only works on NSMutableDictionary.
dict = mutabledict;
```

here we exchange the value of the first declared key **A**.
`mutabledict[@"A"]` **[key]** is a getter subscript used to find the address of the keys value pair. Nothing is changed on the key itself. So the order of keys stays as it was the moment the unique key was copied in.
You need to be careful when you create a mutablecopy, because then whole pairs are copied. The outcome in sorting may be unpredictable as well.
Simple: *But Accessing keys value does not change their memory layout.*

**But:** `NSDictionary` are **immutable**, so the keys can not be changed once they are set. So you can say:
*The keys are ordered in the order they where stored the first time. But you can't access the values stored in a guaranteed order when you don't know the order the keys:value pairs where placed and with this process its unique keys copied into the dict.*

If you can't control the order the keys are set then the keys order is unknown to you, (respecting the question) not undefined. And NSEnumeration  iteration gives you not a real picture of the order they are stored.

How to deal with that?

The easies way to get known ordered sorting of keys is by manually sorting all its keys like..

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [dict.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

which is giving you ascending order of keys and lets you iterate thru your dict with arrays indexes containing addresses to keys. like ..

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<sortedKeys.count; i++) {
    NSString* key = sortedKeys[i];
    dict[ key ] = yourValue;
}
```

if keys are not of interest but the guaranteed sorting is more important to you, then you could convert the NSDictionary into a sorted NSArray without keys and access its indexes in a loop. With the obvious back-draw to have no keys unless you store them manually.

```
id notfoundmarker = @"empty";
NSArray *sortedkeys= [dict.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSArray *oneForOneSorted = [dict objectsForKeys:sortedkeys notFoundMarker:notfoundmarker];
for (unsigned int i=0; i<oneForOneSorted.count; i++) {
    id<NSObject> value = oneForOneSorted[i];
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question was different: if I iterate dictionary once and access keys in some concrete order - will I have the same order on second iteration attempt?

**Short Answer**

In *all probability* **yes**

**Longer Answer**

How a dictionary is constructed internally is not specified, and there are multiple ways to represent dictionaries, all that is known is that key values must be hashable which implies hashing is used *somehow*.

It is also not know what algorithm a dictionary uses to provide the keys when enumerating them, and again for an particular possible representation there could be more than one enumeration algorithm possible.

So we have a lot of unknowns.

What do we know?

In the absence of threading, random number generation, and anything similar an Objective-C program is deterministic, a trait it has in common with C, Swift, Java, C# and a host of other languages.

`NSDictionary` is not thread-safe so its unlikely to use threading in its implementation.

And why would it use random numbers?

`NSDictionary` is also an immutable type so once constructed there is no obvious reason to re-order its internal storage in response to calls querying its contents.

So, in *all probability*, you will get the same key order on every enumeration.

Without the source though you can't be certain, you cannot prove the absence of something by black-box testing. Maybe the programmer decided that every millionth enumeration they'd throw a little randomness in – just for fun ;-) Is this likely? Maybe not (its probably a good way to get fired!), but it's not *impossible*.

If you ask out of curiosity, then good stay curious!

If however you want to rely on the order being deterministic for code correctness then sort the keys (into a peculiar order if you wish as long as its deterministic), the cost of doing so will in *all probability* be inconsequential.

HTH

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html
NSDictionary is threadsafe, it is immutable.

Comment: @OlSen – Curious (or not surprising? ;-)) as I'm pretty sure it says/said somewhere in Apple's docs that it shouldn't be treated as thread-safe, though logically there is little good reason it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

The docs state that for the `allKeys` property the order of the elements in the array is not defined.

So you can just sort the keys array to ensure it's always sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration will be in a random order because Swift dictionaries don't prioritize order. Arrays do, however, so you can sort the dictionary (by key or value) to produce an array of tuples, which in effect can be treated like a sorted dictionary.

```
let dictionary = ["k4": 3, "k2": 8, "k1": 6]
let sortedArrayOfTuples = dictionary.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })

for entry in dictionary {
    print(entry.key)
}

for entry in sortedArrayOfTuples {
    print(entry.key)
}
```